# Remove Sidebars from page

Tags: customization, sidebar, page-template

If I wanted to remove 1 or more sidebars when a certain page is called what is the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: make sure to have a specific css class for the pages without sidebar - for instance by using `body_class()` - this will give you the ability to target the styles of the central content div to stretch the remaining space to fill the full width.

Comment: 8 questions asked, 0 accepted answers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your own theme you could add this to your `page.php` template file

```
if(!is_page('999')) { //Page to exclude sidebar from
    dynamic_sidebar('sidebarID'); 
}
```

Replace `999` with the page ID you wish to exclude, and `sidebarID` with the sidebar you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Copy page.php from your theme and rename to create your custom template.
associate this template with page you want from admin->pages->edit page -> select template.

In your template you can remove side bar as you want...

Here is more info about page templates http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) for your page. In this template you would call your content but not the sidebar. Then you would assign this template to the pages you want in the editor.

Here's a simple tutorial : http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/